# Center TextBox on page

Tags: vb.net, uwp

How can I center a textBox in my Windows 10 App page? I tested 
`button1.Left = (width - button1.width) / 2` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you already tried using the ClientSize.Width for your button1.Location property?

```
button1.Location = New Point((ClientSize.Width - button1.Width) / 2, _
                             (ClientSize.Height - button1.Height) /2)
```

The code should center your control button1 at the center of the Page using Width and Height, but the Point class accept also just a single parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You should leverage the power of the framework instead of doing calculations yourself. There are 2 options to do this using the `HorizontalAlignment` property:

In XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="Button1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Button 1" />
```

In code:

```
Button1.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
```